# YouTube Player View Buffered Video Lost

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

On Orientation change, the buffered video stream is lost and the player reloads the video and then plays it. How to avoid the loss of buffered stream. I have initialised my player in the following way.

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored)
{

    // Checking whether video is restored or not
    if (!wasRestored)
    {
        // If not restored load video
        // Defining player
        player = youTubePlayer;

        // Setting flag for the player to play video in fullscreen mode when switched to landscaper orientation
        player.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);

        // Attaching onFullScreenListener to player
        player.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullScreen)
            {
                // onFullScreen setting flag to true
                playingInFullscreen = isFullScreen;
            }
        });


        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        player.loadVideo(videoId);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("VideoPlayer", "was restored");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the way to do, you can just forbid a recreating of player activity, when orientation changed. In manifest for activity where youtube player is in

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
```

Comment: It worked. But similar thing is observed when I open the share controller used to share the video via Whatsapp, Facebook and other apps

Comment: It's because YotubePlayer detects any overlays over itself (share dialog, fragments, views) and pause playback. If you mean that so. Sorry, but you cannot avoid so behaviour.